# Selenium question: neither css selector or XPath can locate a visible and clickable web element

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath, popup

Here's the link to the website I'm working with: https://www.ftchinese.com/channel/stock.html

Apologies that the website is in Chinese. Basically I'm trying to get the web driver to click on the login button in the header (upper righthand side). [the login button is located in the red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqmJe.jpg) Then a pop up window should show up where you can enter email and password.

I tried locating the element by CSS selector: `login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.visitor-box > a[onclick]')`
and by XPath: `login = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@onclick]')`

Both methods successfully located the login element, but when i did `print(login.size,login.text)`, the returned height and width is 0 and text is empty. However, the login button is visible and there is no overlay. When i tried to click on the button, `login.click()`, it returns the error message "element not interactable".

I also tried the popular answers in similar posts - waiting `time.sleep(5)`, maximizing/setting window size`driver.maximize_window()`, and scrolling to the element first `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", login)`, but had no luck. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with this particular website I'm working with, or the pop up window. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a simple patch of code to log in to your site https://www.ftchinese.com/channel/stock.html

```
login_button=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'登录')]")
login_button.click()
username=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
username.click()
username.send_keys("{{enter username}}")
password=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
password.click()
password.send_keys("{{enter password}}")
submit=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='登录']")
submit.click()
```

Try this out and let me know if it worked for you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but still says element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below solution :

1. I am using Explicit wait, for page loading, and delay issue.
2. Launch the screen in full screen mode.
3. Do not use Chinese or English alphabets in locators.

**Sample code  :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.ftchinese.com/channel/stock.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='overlay-login']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ft-login-input-username"))).send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys("etcasasd12@$")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='login-btn'] input"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't we use Chinese or English alphabets in locators?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have tried this method, but it throws a timeout exception, probably due to the element not becoming clickable.

Comment: @LibinThomas : If you use let's say Chinese character in your locator, it'd work only in Chinese version  of that website. so better to avoid any language specific locators

Comment: @leslie_r  : that's hard to believe, cause it is working fine on my local, at which line you are getting the exception ? Can we have full error stack trace  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I'm getting this error message at line 10:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftlogin.py", line 20, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='overlay-login']"))).click()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/news/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ```

Comment: No I'm using chromeDriver as well, do you have latest one tho ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Your solution works! Actually it's a problem with my chrome driver options. After I deleted the options, it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great ! Can you take a moment and accept and upvote this as an answer. I'd appreciate your time and response on this.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried below xpath. And it clicked on the specified element.
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/a[contains(text(),'登录')]").click()`